# Use QField with Bad Elf device/external GPS/specify GPS

Tags: qgis, gps, qfield

Does anyone know if you can use QField with an external GPS Bluetoothed to the tablet that you are using… specifically a Bad Elf? Wondering if there are settings in QField app that lets you choose what GPS to get location from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Settings, positioning tab, then hit add button shown in image below.

[image]