# Bad Elf not showing location data in QField

Tags: gps, qfield, android, hardware

We have a K88 Android tablet running version 7.1.1 (currrent version is 14 something). I can connect the Bad Elf to the app via Bluetooth, but no positioning data appears to be transmitted. I've attached some images of what the Bad Elf vs QField apps is showing along with info about our operating system. Is the issue that the device is too old, or have I set it up incorrectly?

Essentially, the Bad Elf is connected as an external receiver via bluetooth (NMEA) and is displaying a 17.5 centimeter accuracy, but the QField app is not showing the location icon and reads N/A or 0.0 for all of the accuracy values.

Device model number: K88
Android version: 7.1.1
Baseband Version: K88H01
Kernel version: 3.10.84-perf-ge6bb0d8
Build number: K88V2.0.0B20
Hardware version: u91B

We're running a Bad Elf Flex BE-GPS-5500[image: BadElf shows accuracy but QField does not]

Comment: Qfield in the settings you can change the device internal/external gps [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/460821/use-qfield-with-bad-elf-device-external-gps-specify-gps

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer:  I don't know the Bad Elf, but I've used Trimble external GNSS receivers with various Android devices.

You may need to tell Android to use the Bad Elf application as Mock Location source.  To do this, turn on Developer mode (Settings / About device, scroll down to Build number then tap on the Build number field rapidly 5 or 10 times), then go to Settings / Developer options and scroll down to "Select mock location app", tap on that and select the Bad Elf app.  This tells Android to allow the Bad Elf app to feed the external GNSS receiver locations into Location services.

The above description is for Android 12 or Android 13, other Android versions and non-standard Android versions may have a different mock location setting.